# "Video sniffing's form of parasitical subversion"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The following context is about sniffing CCTV's. What does "Video sniffing’s form of parasitical subversion" mean? And what is its difference from " tapping into live feeds"?

Nicholas Whybrow, *[Art and the City](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0857731475)* (Google Books)

> Video sniffing’s form of ‘parasitical subversion’ by contrast is in itself legal – though the act of tapping into live feeds may not
>   strictly be above board – and it is certainly not damaging to anyone.

Comment: The phrase means exactly what the individual words together mean. For usage/ use-cases, see: https://www.google.com/#q=%22parasitical+subversion%22

Comment: @Kris that link doesn't really help explain it, and the top result is this question :)

Comment: @MaxWilliams ELU posts always tend to be at the top of search results on Google. Try other ones.

Answer (score 2):

Video sniffing is the process of reading a video feed from outside of the equipment actually carrying the feed.  For example, with special equipment you could stand with a laptop under a public CCTV camera, and watch (and record) what the camera is recording, on your laptop: you are "sniffing" that video signal.

If you did this you **would** be "tapping into a live feed", so it's not really "different" to that: it's an example of that.  The difference might be that all the live feeds in this case are in public places (as opposed to a company's security cameras for example), and are available to the public via bureaucratic channels (more on this later).

I'll try and semi-guess the meaning of "parasitical subversion".

"parasitical" is easy - your equipment to read the CCTV camera's feed is a bit like a parasite on that camera, although, unlike a parasite which sucks someone's blood, this process doesn't take anything **away** from the camera - it doesn't use the camera's energy and it doesn't disturb it's function.  It really just reads the radiation which leaks out of the camera in it's normal usage - in this sense it's more like a bug which just sits in your hair keeping warm and eating the occasional bit of dead skin, than something that sucks your blood.

Subversion:  while "subvert" is often used in the context of overthrowing or undermining a goverment, it can also be used when someone uses the government's tools and processes for their own purposes, (which might or might not work against the government somehow).  This article from the UK newspaper The Guardian describes young filmakers who used urban CCTV cameras to record a short film, sniffing the video from them and editing it together.https://www.theguardian.com/culture/2008/apr/25/3

As is often the case with new technology, the law hasn't caught up with it yet.  Since the cameras are in public places, all information captured with them can be requested with the Freedom Of Information Act.  The video sniffers have sidestepped this request and taken it directly, which at the moment is not illegal but it may become so at some point.  I think this is what the author is saying with their "may not be above board" comment - they mean it's legal status is a bit of a "grey area".

EDIT:  I just realised that "tapping into a live feed" might mean "physically accessing it" - like opening some kind of relay box and attaching a cable onto a connector or something.  This is obviously much more invasive than monitoring electromagnetic flux, and more likely to be illegal, since you're tampering with the equipment.  However, I don't think that's what the writer meant.

Comment: I have always assumed that "**tapping** into a live feed" means "physically accessing it". It is only your edit that made me realise that it might be used to refer to non-invasive access.